# Java Collections sort() equal objects

Tags: java

I want to sort a Java list consisting of elements of a class that implements the Comparable interface and has its own compareTo method. What happens when two objects are "equal" (compareTo() returns 0) when compared. Which one ends up before the other in the list?

Comment: Why does it matter if they're equal (according to `compareTo()`)?

Comment: What happens when you test this behavior? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs for [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)* specify that it's a stable sort, which means that in the event of a tie, the elements stay in the same relative order:

> This sort is guaranteed to be *stable*: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

---

<sub>* both overloads</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc says: This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `sort` implementation is guaranteed to be *stable*. That means, that objects, that compare as equal will appear in the same order in the sorted lost as they were in the original.